# validate : on of these fields must be a different value from the current one

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I have a form which contains multiple text inputs , i want to check if at least one of these fields are changed from the current value before processing to the controller.

my form :

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'url']) !!}
   echo Form::text('street_name',$stree_name);
   echo Form::text('state',$state);
   echo Form::text('building_number',$building_number);
   echo Form::text('postal_code',$postal_code);
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

my vaidationRequest :

```
 public function rules()
    {

        return [
            FLD_PROFILES_CITY                       => 'max:50',
            FLD_PROFILES_STREET_NAME                => 'max:150',
            FLD_PROFILES_BUILDING_NUMBER            => 'max:50',
            FLD_PROFILES_POSTAL_CODE                => 'max:10',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: So where are you doing the checks?

Comment: what do you mean changed from the current value? you mean that you have default values inside text inputs??? this is not good. best practice is to let the form inputs be empty and check for invalid inputs. you can use `placeholder` if you want to show something inside the text input.

Comment: @AndyHolmes i have updated my question

Comment: @Moher no , its not like that, i am showing the value of users inputs (edit form)

Comment: Okay so your validation rules show that you have a max length I assume? Where are you trying to determine the difference in the input fields?

Comment: @AndyHolmes well thats my problem , i don't  how to check with multiple fields

Comment: Well you can do it with Vue, with jQuery etc. but I'm struggling to understand the use case for this?

Comment: @AndyHolmes because i want to send email based on changed value, why i should send email if not values changed?

Comment: Are you saying you want to check the input has changed before the information is saved to the database, but also send an email that the values have changed in the database?

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes

Comment: Do you not see the flaw in that?

Comment: @AndyHolmes i am sending an email first so that the admin will confirm with the customer the new data , if confirmed , the admin will submit these data and save it to the database .

Comment: Quite a difference to the issue you've said in your question. Would suggest rewriting it to make it clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your update controller method:

```
$current_stored_item = Address::find($address_id); //you have to send $address_id using a hidden field

//fill the item with the "new" data

$current_stored_item->street_name = $request->street_name;

//do it with all fields

if (empty(array_diff_assoc($current_stored_item ->getOriginal()->forgetKey('updated_at'),$current_stored_item ->getAttributes()->forgetKey('updated_at'))){
   //there are no changes!
}else{
  //there are changes!
}
```